# Problem in combining dropdown menu with horizontal scrollable menu

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I am trying to show dropdown menu inside horizontally long menu. For this purpose, i combined the script of displaying scrollable menu and dropdown menu together. But in this case, dropdown menu is not popping out from the scrollable menu container.

Please review [this](http://article-stack.com/examples/scrollable%20menu.htm) example. And suggest about what css property i can set.

Comment: works in chrome: I see the javascript menu popping out in the lower horizontal scrolling menu. What browser do you have a problem with?

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne: AFAIK, the problem is with the popup menu in the upper area where everything keeps moving around. The upper menu pops up but gets clipped at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have `overflow: hidden` on the `div.sc_menu`. You're telling the browser to clip any child element that tries to render outside the `div.sc_menu`. The solution is to drop the `overflow: hidden`.

If you're using `overflow: hidden` as a clear-fix then you'll have to clear your floats explicitly.

If you can't clear your floats by hand and thus need to keep the `overflow: hidden`, then you could make try making the popup menu a child of `<body>` and then position it by hand on the appropriate hover event; you wouldn't be able to use the standard sucker-fish techniques in this case, you'd have to emulate sucker-fish in JavaScript.